# Use jQuery to add extra html select input fields in form

Tags: jquery, html, forms, append, onchange

Trying to create a form for a travel website. For one of the features I want to have the user select how many children they want to take on their trip. Subsequently, I then want the form to add new select fields the number of which depends on the amount of children selected. This is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<select id="children">
    <option value ="0">0</option>
    <option value ="1">1</option>
    <option value ="2">2</option>
    <option value ="3">3</option>
    <option value ="4">4</option>
    <option value ="5">5</option>
    <option value ="6">6</option>
    <option value ="7">7</option>
</select>
<div id="childrenAge"></div>
```

JS

```
$("select#children").on("change", function() { 
    var number = parseInt($("#children").val());
    var newDropLabel = $("#childrenAge").append("<label>Age of children: </label>");
    var newDropList = $('<select class="Age"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option></select>');
    $("div#childrenAge").append(newDropLabel);
    for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
       $("div#childrenAge").append(newDropList);   
    };
});
```

After selecting a number, this produces the new label and only one new select element. I've checked and the number variable gives the correct number value output. Not quite sure why it's not working.

I also want to add a label to each new select field, something like "Child 1" which increments each time depending on the amount of children chosen.

Any tips would be amazing.

Thanks.

Comment: So, if `2` is selected, you want to add two age-selection `<select>` elements, one for each child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ka4fm9ap/

In this way, whenever you change the number of children will be the exact number of select elements

```
$("select#children").on("change", function () {
    var number = parseInt($("#children").val());

    var label = "<label>Age of children: </label>";
    var newDropList = '<select class="Age"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option></select>';
    var html = '';
    $("#childrenAge").html('');
    html += label;
    for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        html += newDropList
    };

    $("#childrenAge").html(html);
});
```

Comment: This is nice and simple, thanks a lot! Would you have any suggestions of how to add incrementing labels to the new select elements (e.g. Child 1, Child 2 etc)?

Comment: i hava a similar demand i have a multiple select i want foreach option seleted a new input is created is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```js
// binding a change event-handler to the '#children' element:
$('#children').on('change', function() {
  // when using parseInt() don't forget the radix (the number base),
  // in this case '10':
  var n = parseInt(this.value, 10),
  // creating a <label> element, setting its text to 'Age of child':
    label = $('<label />', {
      'text': 'Age of child'
    }),
  // creating a <select> element:
    select = $('<select />', {
      'class' : 'Age'
    }),
  // getting a reference to the element to which the new <select> elements are
  // going to be added, and emptying that element:
    recipient = $('#childrenAge').empty(),
  // empty variables for use within the later loop:
    cloneLabel, cloneSelect;
  // adding <option> elements to the select (for ages 0-17, assuming
  // that 18 is the appropriate age for 'adulthood' to begin):
  for (var o = 0; o < 18; o++) {
    // new Option(0,0) returns an <option> element, setting its value and text to
    // the variable 'o':
    select.append(new Option(o, o));
  }
  // if there's only one child it seems redundant to specify
  // 'child 1', so we just add the relevant <label> and <select>:
  if (n === 1) {
    recipient.append(label.append(select));
  // otherwise (assuming that we have a positive number of children:
  } else if (n > 0) {

    // using a for loop from 0 to the maximum number of children:
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      // cloning the previously created <label> and <select> elements:
      cloneLabel = label.clone();
      cloneSelect = select.clone();

      // appending the cloned <label> to the recipient element:
      recipient.append(cloneLabel.text(function(_, t) {
        // updating the text of the <label>, appending a space and the current
        // value of 'i + 1':
        return t + ' ' + (i + 1);
      // and appending the <select> element to the <label>:
      }).append(cloneSelect));
    }
  }
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
label select {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="children">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
<div id="childrenAge"></div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Option()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement.Option).
  - [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- jQuery:

  - [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
  - [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
  - [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: This is an amazing answer! Thank you for taking the time to write it. However, the other answer above is a lot clearer for me to read at my level so I'll use that, but I will go through your answer and get my head around it. I wish I could up vote it, but my reputation is still low :(

Comment: No worries; obviously I'm biased so while I think I offer a better implementation there's not, really, a lot of difference. Except that in my version the `<label>` elements are used correctly (they should be associated with a specific form-element, not simply used to wrap arbitrary text, to demonstrate click on the `<label>`s in my demo and in the accepted-answer's demo). And I've deliberately accounted for the unnecessary automatic numbering of 'child 1' in the event of there being only one child.